# Which vrata (fastings) should be done by a man for getting a wife or getting married? Any other ritual for getting a wife?

Tags: marriage, fasting, vrata, wife

Which vrata or fasting should be done by a man for getting a wife (a good wife) or getting married?
Are there any other ways(rituals) suggested for a man to get a wife?

Edit: Some People are thinking that I am desperate to get a wife. Lol. No . I for that matter any man can get married whenever he wants but the thing is to get a good religious wife of good character.
Also, It is not only about getting a wife but also about not getting married to a bad person who is not suitable for us.

Comment: So you mean such rituals don't exist and they don't work? How did you assume every unmarried guy has faith in Dharma (like you have) and even try the methods? @Wikash_ It seems you have not learnt any lessons from your previous suspensions at all.

Comment: @Wikash_ you seriously have not learnt any lessons neither from scripture nor from your suspensions. If you do not believe hinduism, you are free to do that but not allowed to post consistently these kind of comments in a hinduism stack exchange where scriptures and rishis works are considered authentic. Stop this behaviour.

Comment: Swayamvara Parvathi mantra is the specific remedy for this problem.

Comment: I would humbly suggest as per my limited understanding to do Ekadashi fasting and Vishnu Sahasrama Parayana. As it is said in Vishnu Sahasranama Phalashruthi that it benefits for all four purusharthas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Patni Manoramam Dehi Manovrittanusarinim |
> Tarinim Durgasansarsagarasya Kulodbhawam ||

This is known as Patni Prapti Mantra

It is 24th shloka of argalastotra which is preceding text of durga sapshati .

https://ia802802.us.archive.org/33/items/DurgaSaptsatiInPdf/durga%20saptsati%20in%20pdf.pdf

This is link for durga saptshati. You can see page no. 41

> Chant this mantra daily on a rosary of red sandal wood. Tuesday, Durgashtami, Navami, Chaturdashi and Navratri are the best Muhurats for starting the chanting of this Mantra. Keep Durgasaptashati Mahayantra or Durgabeesa Yantra at place of worship along with idol of Lord Ganapati and Ashtabhuja Durga at place of worship while chanting Mantra and offer Lal pushp , Lal asan , Lal vastra. This Mantra can also be chanted as a Samput Mantra in Saptashati Paath.

Source - https://www.indianastrology.com/mantra/popular/patni-prapti-mantra-19